# Retrieving Dates in MySql regardless of Years

Tags: mysql, date

I have dates stored in my MySQL database . (ex.: 1992-12-12 , 1983-01-02 , 1983-01-05 , 1983-01-10 )

I want to compare these dates only on Date & Month basis regardless of the years .

Also, i want to retrieve records having date between **2nd January** and **5th January** , whatever the Year be.

How do i do this?
Please help with the MySQL query.

Answer (score 0):

First create a function to extract only the day and month part of the date(I have written to the best of my knowledge, there may be a more optimized way than this):

```
CREATE FUNCTION daymonth (date DATE)
RETURNS DATE
RETURN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CONCAT((EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date)),'-'),(EXTRACT(DAY FROM date))),'%m-%d');
```

Then call the function in your query:

```
SELECT date
FROM ...
WHERE daymonth(date) BETWEEN daymonth('2011-01-02') AND daymonth('2011-01-05');
```

I would love to further discuss on this issue. :)
-Sandip

Answer (score 0):

This request should do what you are looking for. But this will not work perfectly after february because of the 29th

```
SELECT date
FROM ...
WHERE DAYOFYEAR(date) BETWEEN DAYOFYEAR('2011-01-02') AND DAYOFYEAR('2011-01-05');
```

Comment: Wouldn't this approach have problem in comparisons of dates, where one is in a leap year and another in a non-leap year?

Comment: @Fred : sir , if i want to get dates Between 02 Jan AND 01 Feb then??

Comment: @SandipAgarwal Didn't i said that? Look at my post

Comment: @Fred I tried working on the issue, please do correct me in the solution that I have given if I am wrong anywhere. :)